# Combine multiple Haskell functions

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I am wondering if there is an easy way to combine some of these functions together to make it a little more clean. The purpose of the function is to take an int list, and return a list containing all elements that occur after the given occurrence of an int.

```
listAfterFinalKey:: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
```

My code works, I was just wondering if there was a better way of writing it. I would ideally like to have it all be in one function (`listAfterFinalKey`), but I don't know how to make it work other than having three separate functions. I am also avoiding any build in libraries, and things such as let, and where. I would appreciate if someone could show me how to combine or condense some of this code (if possible).

```
listAfterFinalKey:: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
listAfterFinalKey [] x = []
listAfterFinalKey x y = helperFunction1 x y (checker x y 0)

checker:: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
checker [] tracker count = count
checker (x:xs) tracker count = if tracker == x
    then checker xs tracker (count+1)
    else checker xs tracker count


helperFunction1:: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
helperFunction1 [] tracker count = []
helperFunction1 x tracker count = if (count == 0)
    then take 1 x ++ helperFunction1 (drop 1 x) tracker count
    else if (count /= 0) && (tracker == (head x))
    then helperFunction1 (drop 1 x) tracker (count-1)
    else helperFunction1 (drop 1 x) tracker count
```

Comment: Why avoid `let` and `where`? What about guards?

Comment: `listAfterFinalKey xs x = tail $ dropWhile (/=x) xs`. Why "avoiding built-in libraries"?

Comment: The resulting list should have no `x` left. It's still a one-liner though `listAfterFinalKey xs x = (reverse . takeWhile (/= x) . reverse) xs

Comment: @Li-yaoXia My bad. You're right. Please @ me to let me know it the next time :D

Comment: I am avoiding let and where to try and get a better grasp on functional programming. I just did not know if it was possible to condense this down into one or two functions.

Comment: @SnowOnion I am avoiding built in libraries because I want to do it without anything that is already made, so I understand how it works a little better. I want to understand what is going on instead of calling already made functions and libraries (even though I am sure it would make this much easier).

Comment: @SnowOnion, that worked super well! Is there anyway to be able to just return an empty list if the int is not found? Also, if you want to post that as an answer, I can select it as the correct one.

Comment: @SnowOnion - exactly my thoughts, although you need to make sure the result of the dropWhile is non-empty or tail will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get a good feel for functional programming, it's fine to not immediately jump into using all sorts of built-in functions. Many of those functions, however, *are* the embodiment of functional programming, so it's useful to learn to use them, and perhaps learn how to replicate them.

The built-in Haskell modules (and, in fact, all Haskell modules I've ever encountered) are open source, so you can easily go and have a look at how they're implemented.

In order to reproduce the above behaviour, you can implement your own versions of `elem`, `dropWhile` and `tail`:

```
elem' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem'      _    [] = False
elem' target (x:xs) | target == x = True
elem' target (_:xs) = elem' target xs

dropWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhile' _ [] = []
dropWhile' p (x:xs) | p x = dropWhile' p xs
dropWhile' _ xs = xs

tail' :: [a] -> [a]
tail' (_:xs) = xs
```

These three functions work pretty much like their 'official' counterparts - I've just added a `'` as a suffix to all three.

You can now easily implement `listAfterFinalKey` using those three building blocks:

```
listAfterFinalKey :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
listAfterFinalKey xs target | not (elem' target xs) = xs
listAfterFinalKey xs target = tail' (dropWhile' (/= target) xs)
```

As far as I can tell, it behaves like the OP version:

```
*Q48735389> listAfterFinalKey [0..9] 3
[4,5,6,7,8,9]
*Q48735389> listAfterFinalKey [0..9] 11
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
*Q48735389> listAfterFinalKey [0..9] (-1)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
*Q48735389> listAfterFinalKey [1,2,3,2,1] 2
[3,2,1]
```

Not only does it drop all elements before it encounters the `target`, it also returns the original list if the `target` isn't present at all. This is, AFAICT, also the behaviour of the OP function.

In general, `head` (and `head'`) is unsafe, because it'll throw an exception when passed an empty list. In this simple function, however, this should never happen because `tail'` is only called in the case where we *know* that there's at least one occurrence of `target` in `xs`.

Note also that the type of `listAfterFinalKey` is more general than the OP version.